How to detect the correct User-Agent in Android Apps, running in ChromeOS?
I have written this basic code to detect the kind of app where my hybrid Android app is running, desktop, tablet, and phone:
​var deviceDetector = (function() {
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

    var detectDevice = function(ua) {
        ua = ua.toLowerCase();

        // Check for ChromeOS specifically
        if (/cros/.test(ua)) {
            return "desktop";
        }

        // Check for Android TV specifically
        if (/android.*tv/.test(ua)) {
            return "desktop";
        }

        // Check for tablets
        if (/ipad|tablet|(android(?!.*mobile))|(windows(?!.*phone)(.*touch))|kindle|playbook|silk|(puffin(?!.*(IP|AP|WP)))/.test(ua)) {
            return "tablet";
        }

        // Check for phones
        if (/mobi|ipod|phone|blackberry|opera mini|fennec|minimo|symbian|psp|nintendo ds|archos|skyfire|puffin|blazer|bolt|gobrowser|iris|maemo|semc|teashark|uzard/.test(ua)) {
            return "phone";
        }

        // Default to desktop
        return "desktop";
    };

    var detectedDevice = detectDevice(userAgent);

    return {
        device: detectedDevice,
        detect: detectDevice,
        isMobile: detectedDevice !== "desktop",
        userAgent: userAgent
    };
})();

It works quite well in the majority of cases but fails in Chromebooks since instead of showing the Tablet or Desktop UIs, it always displays the Android Mobile one.
The app still works fine, but for the landscape modes, it loses its main advantages and the UI breaks from time to time. Do you have any idea how I can fix it or to detect the proper User-Agent? It should return it's running in a desktop.
Notes:
I already tried to contact the Chromium OS forum without any replies: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-os-discuss
Furthermore, if you wonder how do I know that is returning the wrong user agent? The Play Store videos show me previews. This is how it looks in ChromeOS at the present time:

And this is how it should look:

There are considerable differences. The 1st UI is not as responsive as it should be and that is correct since it's planned for phones, not for large screen devices.
This is the Play Store preview video:

And these are the tested devices by the Play Store:

Only in ChromeOS, the UI is somehow broken since it's using the wrong User-Agent.

"However, it doesn't work as expected since in Chromebooks instead of showing the Tablet or Desktop UI, it always displays the Android Mobile one" What does that mean?  Does it mean it returns the wrong result from your detectDevice function? If yes, what is the actual useragent when running on chromeos?

Hi @derpirscher, it always return phone even though ChromeOS is a desktop.

So, obviously your /cros/.test(ua) doesn't match the actual useragent. Thus my question, What is the value of userAgent when you run your app on a ChromeBook?

That's something I don't know well @derpirscher, how do I know the results are incorrect and it's returning the Android Mobile one? The videos from the Play Store showed me the previews of the UI in Chromebooks. The UI in landscape mode is the Android Landscape Mobile one. My PWA has different UIs and is displaying the wrong one when it is running it in landscape.

"That's something I don't know" Well then attach a debugger or do some kind of logging output to find out. You do have access to such a device, don't you? If not, how do you do the testing?

Hi @derpirscher, I added extra details in the notes.

And if in fact the UA are indistinguishable (because as far as I know ChromeOS runs android apps in some sort of container), you can still check in the android app, whether it is running in chromeOS like shown here and then set a custom useragent on the webview.

Hi @derpirscher, I tried it multiple times and doesn't work as expected. I even expanded it in my answer, but I cannot consider it's a good idea. I created this Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tafk1qwx/, but I couldn't get any replies in Reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/1eiiok4/how_does_the_useragent_look_of_a_website_or_a_web/

Just confirming you tested on different emulators "Desktop" and "Phone"->"Chromebook Pixel 2015 (beta)"? Also have you seen/gone through all of the documentation for Android devs for ChromeOS: https://developer.android.com/chrome-os/intro

Hi @MorrisonChang, yes, I have tested it. That's not my problem. My app works perfectly on TVs, Tablets in landscape and portrait modes and mobile devices in the same way, even in very small Android devices. My issue is specifically with ChromeOS only since my app behaves like a mobile in landscape mode. It stills works, but it shows a very poor UI since I cannot detect it well.

My challenge stays the same @MorrisonChang. The documentation doesn't tell me how to detect if it's running in ChromeOS. The app as in the screenshots are shown is running "fine." It will work, but the user experience will be poorer.

From what I found since the app is running in a kind of container, there is not a proper way to detect it via JavaScript (for now). I had to create a kind of hack for my app before the WebView was loaded (I'm using .NET 8):
// Set the custom user agent if ChromeOS is detected
if (IsChromeOS(this))
{
    string chromeOSUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12345) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36";
    MyWebView.Settings.UserAgentString = chromeOSUserAgent;
}

private bool IsChromeOS()
{
    try
    {
        PackageManager packageManager = PackageManager;

        // Check for system feature
        bool hasArcFeature = packageManager.HasSystemFeature("org.chromium.arc.device_management");

        // System properties
        bool isChromeOSDevice = Build.Fingerprint != null && Build.Fingerprint.Contains("chrome");

        // Known device models
        string[] knownChromebooks = { "Chromebook", "Chromebox", "ChromeOS" };
        bool isKnownChromebook = knownChromebooks.Any(keyword => Build.Model.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        return hasArcFeature || isChromeOSDevice || isKnownChromebook;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}


I got some inspiration from here: How to find if android app is started by AndroidOS or ChromeOS's android container?
In a way, you're injecting a custom user agent. It's not exactly the best/correct answer (for me) because it is not bullet proof since it might fail in some cases. I still raised a ticket in the ChromiumOS forums, but I'd say it's a good enough "hack" for the moment. If anyone has a better solution please feel free to add it.
